# How to install Modsecurity 2.9.6 on Debian 11 with Apache2?

Tags: owasp, mod-security2, apache2-module

If you want you use the new CRS versions you need at least 2.9.6 of libapache2-mod-security2. see:
https://coreruleset.org/installation/

Is this possible on Debian11? I searched for backports but couldn't find any method on getting this version. Default Debian 11 Version 2.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want you use the new CRS versions you need at least 2.9.6 of libapache2-mod-security2. see: https://coreruleset.org/installation/

Thanks, we (CRS team) should add some links to this documentation.

> Is this possible on Debian11? I searched for backports but couldn't find any method on getting this version. Default Debian 11 Version 2.9.3

We are working on it, that Debian 11 accepts this version too. Actually, the Debian's package source repository already has the patched 2.9.3:

https://salsa.debian.org/modsecurity-packaging-team/modsecurity-apache/-/blob/bullseye/debian/changelog

You can download that and make an own package.

If you want to avoid to make a custom/own package, follow this [link](https://coreruleset.org/docs/deployment/install/#option-1-installing-pre-packaged-modsecurity), and you can try the [Digitalwave's ModSecurity repository](https://modsecurity.digitalwave.hu). There you can find the 2.9.6 for Debian 10, 11, Ubuntu 18.04, 20,04 and 22.04.

Note: I'm CRS developer, and Debian maintainer. I made the packages for Debian too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the DigitalWave repository and it seems to work.